# Unable to setText() on TextView because of NullPointer

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a fragment of the MainActivity which has a `ListView`. Each `ListView` item has three `TextViews`. I made a custom adapter used on the `ListView` and this custom adapter is where I tried to use `setText()` on the three different `TextView`. Two of the `TextViews` are able to update, but the problem is the line `nameTextView.setText(singleAppt.getName());`. I think the problem is that `singleAppt.getName()`returns a null value since the `TextView` shows up as blank, but I'm not sure why it is null.

Custom adapter: (problem is here)

```
public class AppointmentList extends ArrayAdapter<SingleAppointment> {
private Activity context;
List<SingleAppointment> appointments;

public AppointmentList(Activity context, List<SingleAppointment> appointments) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_appt_list, appointments);
    this.context = context;
    this.appointments = appointments;
}

public void updateAppointmentList(List<SingleAppointment> appointments) {
    this.appointments = appointments;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appt_list, null, true);

    TextView nameTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    TextView addressTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);
    TextView dateTextView = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);

    SingleAppointment singleAppt = appointments.get(position);

    if(singleAppt != null && singleAppt.getName() != null) {
        nameTextView.setText(singleAppt.getName());
    }
    if(singleAppt != null && singleAppt.getAddress() != null) {
        addressTextView.setText(singleAppt.getAddress());
    }
    if(singleAppt != null && singleAppt.getDate() != null) {
        dateTextView.setText(singleAppt.getDate());
    }

   // addressTextView.setText(singleAppt.getAddress());
   // dateTextView.setText(singleAppt.getDate());

    return listViewItem;
}
```

}

MainActivity fragment:

```
public class Appointments extends Fragment {

View myView;

AppointmentList appointmentAdapter;
ArrayList<SingleAppointment> appointments;
ListView appointmentList;

DatabaseReference databaseAppointments;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    databaseAppointments = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("appointments");

    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.appointments, container, false);

    Button newApptButton = myView.findViewById(R.id.newApptButton);
    newApptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), EditApptActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    appointmentList = myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    appointments = new ArrayList<>();
    appointmentAdapter = new AppointmentList(getActivity(), appointments);
    appointmentList.setAdapter(appointmentAdapter);

    return myView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseAppointments.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            appointments.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                SingleAppointment singleAppt = postSnapshot.getValue(SingleAppointment.class);
                appointments.add(singleAppt);
            }
            appointmentAdapter.updateAppointmentList(appointments);
            appointmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Activity where user edits the `TextViews`:

```
public class EditApptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference databaseAppointments;
ArrayList<SingleAppointment> appointments;

Button bookButton;

EditText clientEditText;
EditText addressEditText;
EditText dateEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_appt);

    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    clientEditText = findViewById(R.id.clientEditText);
    addressEditText = findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
    dateEditText = findViewById(R.id.dateEditText);

    databaseAppointments = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("appointments");

    bookButton = findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
    bookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addAppointment();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void addAppointment() {
    String name = clientEditText.getText().toString();
    String address = addressEditText.getText().toString();
    String date = dateEditText.getText().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(address) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(date)) {
        String id = databaseAppointments.push().getKey();
        SingleAppointment singleAppt = new SingleAppointment(id, name, address, date);
        databaseAppointments.child(id).setValue(singleAppt);

        clientEditText.setText("");
        addressEditText.setText("");
        dateEditText.setText("");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid name, address, and date.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

SingleAppointment.java class (each `ListView` item is one of these objects):

```
public class SingleAppointment {
private String id;
private String clientName;
private String address;
private String date;

public SingleAppointment() {}

public SingleAppointment(String clientName, String address, String date) {
    this.clientName = clientName;
    this.address = address;
    this.date = date;
}

public SingleAppointment(String id, String clientName, String address, String date) {
    this.id = id;
    this.clientName = clientName;
    this.address = address;
    this.date = date;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return clientName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

}

Comment: You can provide samples from your code, but please don't give us all of it. We cannot debug your code for you. Be more specific.

Comment: What's the error you get? On what line does it happen?

Comment: As @26hmkk commented: there is more code in your question than most of us will be interested in reading. If you reproduce the same problem in less code, you're more likely to get answers and less likely to get downvoted. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for an explanation on how to do this, and why it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check nameTextView value is not Null